# Why can't I call the methods method on a Perl 6's ClassHOW object?

Tags: metaclass, raku

I can call `^methods` on an object and list the method names I can call:

```
my $object = 'Camelia';
my @object_methods = $object.^methods;
@object_methods.map( { .gist } ).sort.join("\n").say;
```

[`^methods`](https://doc.perl6.org/routine/methods#role_Metamodel::MethodContainer) returns a list which I store in `@object_methods`, then later I transform that list of method thingys by calling [`gist`](https://doc.perl6.org/type/Mu#routine_gist) on each one to get the human-sensible form of that method thingy.

But, the `^` in `^methods` is an implied `.HOW`, as show at the end of the [object documentation](https://doc.perl6.org/language/objects) this should work too:

```
my $object = 'Camelia';
my @object_methods = $object.HOW.methods;
```

But, I get an error:

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1
  in any methods at gen/moar/m-Metamodel.nqp line 490
  in block <unit> at...
```

And, for what it's worth, this is an awful error message for a language that's trying to be person-friendly about that sort of thing. The file *m-Metamodel.nqp* isn't part of my perl6 installation. It's not even something I can google because, as the path suggests, it's something that a compilation generates. And, that compilation depends on the version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular method call via `.` passes the invocant as implicit first argument to the method. A meta-method call via `.^` passes two arguments: the meta-object as invocant, and the instance as first positional argument.

For example

```
$obj.^can('sqrt')
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
$obj.HOW.can($obj, 'sqrt')
```

In your example, this would read

```
my @object_methods = $object.HOW.methods($object);
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: In the very same document you linked to, the language/objects, it says: "The calling convention for methods on meta objects is to call the method on the meta object and pass in the object of interest as first argument to the object.", and also says that "say 1.^name;" is "same as" "say 1.HOW.name(1);"

Comment: That's an example that I see more clearly now, but the [documentation for the method](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/methods#role_Metamodel::MethodContainer) is lacking. It notes that it inspects a class and  it does show an $obj argument, but I expected that to be the ClassHOW object (which I expected to already know who made it).

Comment: @briandfoy: the metaobject is shared between instances of a class and might be even more generic (ie shared between all objects) in prototypal object systems; therefore, the instance has to be passed seperately

Comment: everything before the : in a method signature refers to the invocant, everything afterwards is the full signature. That has to be understood by the reader (and - on the flip side - clearly communicated and explained by the docs). that's why the documentation for the methods method isn't lacking, but the documentation in general is. that's my first opinion anyway :)